# How to update components URL based on events from other components

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I am working on a application where i have 3 components: `Component1`, `Component2` and `Component3`. All components retrieve data from a RESTful service with AJAX. `Component1` will retrieve a list of data when the application has been initialized. Each item in `Componet1`, is a link which will retrieve data for `Component2` based on its key/id when clicked. The same goes for `Component2`, which will retrieve data for `Component3` in the same fashion.

So if we imagine following main component:

```
var ComponentItems = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <li className="list-group-item" key={this.props.data.id}><a onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.data.name}</a></li>;        
    },
    handleClick: function () {
      this.props.onClick(this);
    }
});

var Component1 = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {componentsList: []};
    },
    componentWillMount: function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          this.setState(data);
          console.log(data);
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
          console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
      });
    },
    render: function() {
        var componentItems = this.state.componentsList.map(function (item) {
            return <ComponentItem data={item} onClick={this.handleClick} />;
        });
        return (
            <div className="col-lg-3">
                <ul className="list-group">
                    {componentItems}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    },
    handleClick: function (aComponent) {
      alert("test");
    }
});    
var MainComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
        <div>
            <Component1 url="/api/dataSource1/" />
            <Component2 />
            <Component3 />
        </div>
        );
    }
});
```

As you can see in this example i have not implemented `Component2` or `Component 3`. But when a `ComponentItem` is clicked i want to call a AJAX URL in`Component2` with its key, eg. if the item has key 3:

```
<Component2 url="/api/dataSource2/3`>
```

I am not certain how i should be structuring the program and whether the click handling should be done within the `MainComponent` or `Component1`?

Another thing which may be a bit out of the scope of this example is multiple selection of `Component 2`, which will pass an array of key/id.

Comment: Added a new answer with simpler solution (removed bind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it is better to handle click in MainComponent as it has access to component2 directly.

In `ComponentItem`

```
var ComponentItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <li className="list-group-item" key={this.props.data.id}><a onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.data.name}</a></li>;        
  },
  handleClick: function () {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.data);
  }
});
```

In `Component1` render method can be like below in order to get the key of clicked item.

```
handleClick: function (aComponent) {
  this.props.onClick(aComponent);
}

render: function() {
    var componentItems = this.state.componentsList.map(function (item) {
        return <ComponentItem data={item} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />;
    }, this);
    return (
        <div className="col-lg-3">
            <ul className="list-group">
                {componentItems}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
},
```

In `MainComponent` you can have a reference to Component2 and as soon as the event is captured you can do something like the below

```
var MainComponent = React.createClass({
      handleClick: function(index){
        this.refs.component2.setState({
          url: '/api/dataSource2/' + index
        });
      },
      render: function() {
          return (
          <div>
              <Component1 url="/api/dataSource1/" onClick={this.handleClick}/>
              <Component2 ref="component2" />
              <Component3 />
          </div>
          );
      }
  });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So far so good, `this.props.onClick(this.props.data);`  in  `ComponentItems` is giving `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.  What may be wrong?

Comment: just noticed, shouldn't it be `ComponentItem` instead of `ComponentItems`?

Comment: Woops. That is a typo! Everything is working, except when i click a link.

Comment: What do you see by doing console.log(this.props); inside handleClick method of ComponentItem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71390/discussion-between-dhiraj-bodicherla-and-javacake).